# aspect multicasting in postsharp

Tags: c#, postsharp

I've a simple aspect:

```
[System.Serializable()]
[System.AttributeUsage(System.AttributeTargets.Assembly)]
[PostSharp.Extensibility.MulticastAttributeUsage(PostSharp.Extensibility.MulticastTargets.Method)]
public class NullableMethodCallAspect : PostSharp.Aspects.MethodInterceptionAspect
{

    public override void OnInvoke(PostSharp.Aspects.MethodInterceptionArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Instance != null)
            args.Proceed();
    }

}
```

I've two projects inside my solution: `UI` and `UIAppearanceExtensibility` (this is referenced by `UI`).

In the second one, I declare some interfaces in order for other developers to use them for creating several implementations according those interfaces.

From `UI`, I declare properties of those interfaces, for example `IInterface1`.

So, from my UI project (assembly), I need to apply my aspect to every call to `IInterface1` objects...

I've tried that, but, it doesn't work:

```
[assembly: UI.Aspects.NullableMethodCallAspect(
    AttributeTargetAssemblies = "UIAppearanceExtensibility",
    AttributeTargetTypes = "UI.Appearance.Extensibility.Triage.*",
    AttributeTargetMembers = "regex: handle*"
)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the shown example the calls to interface members will be intercepted in the UI assembly, but only when they are accessed through the variable of the interface type.

For example:

```
// Interface in UIAppearanceExtensibility 
public interface IInterface1
{
    void Method1();
}

// Class in UI
public class Class1 : IInterface1
{
    // ...
}

// This usage in UI will be intercepted
IInterface1 i1 = new Class1();
i1.Method1();

// This usage in UI will not be intercepted
Class1 c1 = new Class1();
c1.Method1();
```

The reason is that the IL code generated by compiler in the second case does not reference `IInterface1` and PostSharp is looking for the usages of `IInterface1` when applying the aspect.

In your case it's probably better to apply the aspect to the interfaces in the `UIAppearanceExtensibility` assembly itself, and set `AttributeInheritance` property to `MulticastInheritance.Strict`. The attribute will then be multicast to the classes implementing the interface. This use case is documented in [Understanding Aspect Inheritance](http://doc.postsharp.net/multicast-inheritance).

```
// In the UIAppearanceExtensibility project
[assembly: UI.Aspects.NullableMethodCallAspect(
    AttributeInheritance = MulticastInheritance.Strict
    AttributeTargetTypes = "UI.Appearance.Extensibility.Triage.*",
    AttributeTargetMembers = "regex: handle*"
)]
```